# Applying two-point forward to two-point forward formula

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

What do you get when you apply the two-point forward finite difference formula for the first derivative of  $f(x)$ to the two-point forward finite difference formula for the first derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Can you please clarify your question? It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The two-point forward finite difference formula for the first derivative of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ is given by the expression

$$\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}.$$

Recall that this is an approximation of $f'(x_0)$:

$$f'(x_0) \approx \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h}.$$

If you apply this formula to the first derivative of $f$, the resulting expression is

$$\frac{f'(x_0 + h) - f'(x_0)}{h}.$$

From earlier, we know that this should be an approximation of the first derivative of $f'$ at the point $x_0$.

What is the first derivative of $f'$?